# Is there a SubEthaEdit-like plugin for for TextMate?

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles

It would be fantastic to edit the same file as a neighbor in real time, à la [SubEthaEdit](http://www.codingmonkeys.de/subethaedit/), in Textmate. [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) does this. Is there a way to hack this stuff into TextMate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any collaborative editing plugin for TextMate. It used to be a requested feature right from the start but I think Allan said early that he didn't want it.

As for the hacking part, I would say you'd need access to the source which is impossible since it is closed. I don't think the plugin infrastructure is built with that kind of thing in mind.

Plus, what I imagine would be collaborative coding seems awfully nightmarish.

Answer (score 1):

This should be feasible with TextMate 2 now since it is open source.  It would be worthwhile to explore this. Further it would be worth making this work with SublimeText as well since there is a good degree of compatibility between the two.